# How to adjust position of FBLoginView inside a view?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login

I'm adding facebook login button graphically, but I've got a problem with it's variable height when user is using different language.

**This is what it looks like:**

[image: FBLoginView]

I want to be able to set distance between facebook login view and the other view to be always the same, but the problem is the height of the facebook button itself is smaller than 60 (my case) when you have english language, but it's bigger in other languages. How to achieve that? Is it possible to have the button itself always on bottom of the view? Or via autolayout? Somehow? Thanks for any help.

**This is what it looks like in ios simulator:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with your design, use Custom button for facebook login and call the following code on button click.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet  UIButton *LoginLogout;

FBSession session;
NSDictionary *permissions;

- (void)updateView {
    // get the app delegate, so that we can reference the session property

    if (self.session.isOpen) {
        // valid account UI is shown whenever the session is open

        [self.LoginLogout setText:@"Log out" ];


    } 
     else {
        // login-needed account UI is shown whenever the session is closed
        [self.LoginLogout setText:@"Login with Facebook" ];

    }
}
// handler for button click, logs sessions in or out
- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {
    // get the app delegate so that we can access the session property

    // this button's job is to flip-flop the session from open to closed
    if (self.session.isOpen) {
        // if a user logs out explicitly, we delete any cached token information, and next
        // time they run the applicaiton they will be presented with log in UX again; most
        // users will simply close the app or switch away, without logging out; this will
        // cause the implicit cached-token login to occur on next launch of the application
        [self.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];


    } else {
       if (self.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
            // Create a new, logged out session.
          self.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        }

        // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
        [[self.session  initWithPermissions:self.permissions]openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                                                        FBSessionState status,
                                                                                                        NSError *error) {
            // recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels

            [self updateView];
        }];


    }
}
```

The login response should be handled in Appdelegate. So include the following function in Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {



    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled =NO;


    wasHandled=[FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:self.session];


    return wasHandled;

}
```

Comment: for more info go to this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0 and got the Heading "Build your Own Button"